# .net: Is this file in use?

Tags: vb.net, io, file-copying

I've seen multiple version of this question on this site, but none seems to address my precie problem, so here it is:

I'm trying to copy a file, using `System.Copy`. The destination, if it exists, should be overwritten. I had been using a single line of code for about a month, without problems :

```
IO.File.Copy(SourceFile, DestFile, True)
```

But problems started about a week ago, when I started more advanced checks. Partially locked files fail to copy, **and** the destination gets deleted. Locked files, on the other hand, work correctly: they just trigger a file in use exception.

So I added this line before launching the copy:

```
Using TestForAccess As New IO.FileStream(SourceFile, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.None)  : End Using
```

This was supposed to launch an error if the file was in use. But it is to sensitive. Some files (such as thunderbird's abook.mab) trigger an error in this added code, whereas they copied fine before (and you can copy them in explorer).

My question basically is: **How do I tell the system: copy `source` to `destination` if possible; if not, don't break `destination`?**

Thanks for your help, this thing is driving me nuts.

Comment: You should be aware that the file can become in use after your check, but right before the copy.

Comment: Sure, but that's a corner case that I can't avoid. I'm thinking of solutions to this very specific problem, but right now I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place, where the first line of code erases the destination when the source is partially locked (eg outlook pst files), whereas adding the second line enforces to strong checks.

Comment: I mentioned it because I don't know what kind of files you are copying. In many situations it doesn't matter, but sometimes it does, so you should be aware of it when making your decision.

Comment: And you're right; but I'm still searching for a solution to my very specific problem: how do I tell the system: copy the file if you can, but don't alter the destination if you can't read the source? I've edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two step process--copy to a temp file, then rename to destination.  That way if the copy fails, the destination file won't be overwritten.

Even better, you four steps. copy to temp, rename dest to other temp, rename temp to dest, delete other temp.

My VB is rusty, but something like this:

```
Dim DestTemp As String = DestFile + ".temp"
Dim DestBack As String = DestFile + ".bak"
File.Copy(SourceFile, DestTemp, True)
File.Move(DestFile, DestBack)
File.Move(DestTemp, DestFile)
File.Delete(DestBack)
```

Comment: Won't this have an impact on performance for remote locations? Eg. on a network drive. I thought it would, which is why I didn't do it that way...

Comment: Actually, I could use this as a fallback: if the first test fails, use this approach.

Comment: I would still love to see a prettier solution, though =)

Comment: Another problem is with big files: at some point, you're using twice more space than needed.

Comment: This should not have any noticeable impact on performance.  There's still only one `File.Copy` call.  After that, everything is a `Move` or `Delete` which are both very fast.

Comment: Hmm, Move seems to have a very bad behaviour on network drives. Per my test, moving a file locally (`C:\ay5x8kqs.0if -> C:\ay5x8kqs.0if-`) takes about 0.3ms on average, whereas it takes about 163ms remotely (`\\192.168.0.200\qtr715vt.mwy -> \\192.168.0.200\qtr715vt.mwy-`). I did tests with 16MiB, 32MiB, and 128MiB files on randomly generated data, and executed about 200000 move operations in the first case, and 20000 in the second.

Comment: @CFP, 163ms doesn't sound like very long at all.

Comment: @Samuel, it adds about one hour (50 minutes) every 20'000 files. Assuming a copy speed of 5MiB/s (reasonable lan), and a total size of 1GiB (50KiB/file), copying takes about 100s, perhaps 500s (about 9 minutes) with additional overhead, while moving takes 50 minutes. Not that fast, is it?

Comment: @CFP, it doesn't make any sense that copying files across a network would be slower than moving (renaming) files on a remote machine.

Comment: @CFP, if rename really did take longer like you're saying then you could just copy the file locally first and then move it from local to remote.

Comment: @Samuel: But that would imply writing on the source drive, which may be protected, or full, and so on. Anyway, accepted, although I do believe that timing issues are worth mentioning. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're using IO.FileShare.None.

That implies that the file CANNOT be shared by any additional threads. Since the file is already open that will fail, even though a copy would work, since copies usually open a file in READ share mode

You might try IO.FileShare.Read instead.

Comment: Nope, it raises the same error for files copying successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your code in a try/catch block.

in c# use - you can substitute the exception type with IOException

```
FileStream fileStream = null;  
try 
{     
fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write); 
} 
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e) 
{
} 
finally 
{     
if (fileStream != null)         
fileStream.Close (); 
}
```

Comment: This does not address the problem at all; raising an exception is fine; the only problem is that the code that you suggest is too sensitive. If I substitute the exception type as you mentioned, I will get `IOException`s for files that would have copied successfully.